# Wordpress - Pagination of All Parent and Child Pages in Order

Tags: php, html, wordpress, pagination

I'm developing a website for a webcomic I'm working on.  I currently have two custom taxonomies, Series (I plan on eventually producing different series for the site) and Page Type.  Page Type contains three types - Volume Cover, Chapter Cover, and Standard Page, with every Chapter Cover and Standard Page being the child of a Volume Cover.  It's this last part which is causing me trouble.

I have a series of pagination buttons that aren't acting as I want them to.  Every time I click the "next" button, I want the order to go like this:

- Volume 1 (Volume Cover)
- Vol 1/Page 1 (Chapter Cover)
- Vol 1/Page 2 (Standard Page)
- Vol 1/Page 3 (Standard Page)
- Volume 2 (Volume Cover)
- Vol 2/Page 1 (Chapter Cover)
- Vol 2/Page 2 (Standard Page)
- Vol 2/Page 3 (Standard Page)

When currently it goes like this:

- Vol 1/Page 1 (Chapter Cover)
- Vol 1/Page 2 (Standard Page)
- Vol 1/Page 3 (Standard Page)
- Vol 2/Page 1 (Chapter Cover)
- Vol 2/Page 2 (Standard Page)
- Vol 2/Page 3 (Standard Page)
- Volume 1 (Volume Cover)
- Skips to the series home page for some bizarre reason
- Volume 2 (Volume Cover)

Previously I had all the Volume Covers on the same level as everything else with no parent-child hierarchy, and it worked exactly as I wanted with the code below (I changed it because I wanted the URLs to be cleaner).  Here's the code I'm using for the next button, the previous button works exactly the same way:

```
<!-- Next Button -->
<?php if( get_next_post($in_same_term = true, $excluded_terms = '', $taxonomy = 'comic-series') ) : ?>

    <button class="light-button comic-button">
        <?php next_post_link('%link', '>', $in_same_term = true, $excluded_terms = '', $taxonomy = 'comic-series'); ?>
    </button>

<?php endif; ?>
```

The reason I'm confused is because as all the pages are in the same taxonomy (the same series), so the way I figure they should go in the order presented on the Wordpress page showing all my comic pages.  Clearly that's not how the built-in pagination function works though, and I'd be super appreciative if anyone who knows more about this subject could help me find a workaround.  My backup plan is going back to my old system but this way has advantages so I'd like to do it this way if possible.  Thanks!

P.S. - if it helps, here's an example URL showing off the current URL structure.  "comics" is the custom post type slug, "lcc" is the series slug, "volume-01" is the volume slug, "page-03" is the page slug.

```
http://localhost/wordpress/comics/lcc/volume-01/page-03/
```

Comment: when you say "the order presented on the Wordpress page," are you referring to a posts page in the administration area (back end)?

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have been less ambiguous in my wording.  I'm trying to get the comic pages to appear in the same order as on the page on the backend, irrespective of what type of comic page it is.  (Just to be clear when I say "comic page," a comic page is actually a type of custom *post* I created, not a "page" in the sense that Wordpress uses that term.  I realize that could get a bit confusing if I don't clarify).

Comment: Well I figured out that the cause of the issue was that it's being sorted by the post ID, so I guess I have to figure out a workaround for that.

Comment: You might be able to squeeze it into automated form, but you might want to maintain at least some flexibility on ordering without having to re-program. Either way, I think you'll want to examine the "orderby" options on the query, and then apply some level of customized pagination (see `paginate_links()`. I doubt that `get_next_post()` and `next_post_link()` will suffice.a) What do the "volume cover" and "chapter cover" slugs look like? b)  It might also be helpful if you showed the query that's being used... if you want a possibly working example to look at.